# Switch tabs inside tab in tabpane TornadoFX

Tags: tornadofx

I have

```
root= tabpane {
        tab(FirstView::class)
        tab(SecondView::class)         
    }
```

And I would like in my FirstView switch tab after I click a button. I can't figure out how to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this for example:

```
private lateinit var tabPane: TabPane
private lateinit var tabFront: Tab

root = tabpane {
        tabPane=this
        tab { tabFront = this}
        tab { }
    }
...
button("go front tab") {
  action {
    tabPane.selectionModel.select(tabFront)
  }
}

button("another go front tab") {
  action {
    tabFront.select()
  }
}
```

Look for JavaFX `getSelectionModel()`